# Python - how to fix the parse from ini file the correct values, but not parse values from values field

Tags: python, parsing, ini

Parsing wrong value from ini file, how can i parse the username from username= field not from the value?

**1)** Ini file stored with predefined presets, which i need to read in python

```
$ cat /var/tmp/file.ini
banner=QUESTIONS sentence
network=lan
programming=pytohn
url=http\://pbx/register?username=E300B1&password=1234&option=localip&localip=
username=E300B1
password=1234
server=pbx
```

**2)** Code: i was trying seems wrong for username/password field

```
import re,os, time, socket, datetime, threading, subprocess, logging, gtk, gobject
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/tmp/log.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

def readini(findme):
  f = open('/var/tmp/file.ini', "r")
  for line in f:
    if line:
      if findme in line:
        r= line.split("=")
        return r[1].replace("\\n", "").rstrip()

host = readini("server")
username = preadini("username")
password = readini("password")

command = """curl 'http://%s/a/b?username=%s&password=%s&language=EN'""" % (host, username, password)
logging.debug( command )
os.system( command )
```

**3)** outputs (wrong):

```
DEBUG:root:curl 'http://192.168.1.10/a/b?username=http\://pbx/register?username&password=http\://pbx/register?username&language=EN'
```

**4)** expected output was:

```
DEBUG:root:curl 'http://192.168.1.10/a/b?username=E300B1&password=1234&language=EN'
```

Comment: Assuming, you are in control of configuration file format, there are better options available: either try standard python module ConfigParser, or (my favorite solution) use YAML format for config file and read it into dictionary by `import yaml` followed by `cfg = yaml.load(open("config.yaml"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your condition `if findme in line` does not work with your file. In your file, the string "username" is in the line defining the url -- which is why you're seeing the output that you're seeing.

```
 url=http\://pbx/register?username=E300B1&password=1234&option=localip&localip=
```

A better approach would be:

```
def readini(findme):
  f = open('/var/tmp/file.ini', "r")
  for line in f:
    if "=" in line:
        key,val = line.split("=",1)
        if findme in key:
            return val.replace("\\n", "").rstrip()
```

Using the optional int arg to split guarantees that the list returned has length two and that it will actually be the key,val pair defined by that line.

Comment: Maybe limit to one split? ```line.split("=", maxsplit = 1))[:1]``` Just in case it is used on a line with multiple *=* signs.

Comment: wwii, I did limit the split (including the keyword arg `maxsplit` is unnecessary, implied). Including the `[:1]` is also redundant in this case.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what I was looking at.